# remove specific keys (and values) from a ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash of words and counts

```
result_hash
# => {"should"=>1790.8069584736252,
# "is"=>1580.7037037037037,
# "may"=>1562.1964085297418,
# "used"=>1452.4938271604938,
```

and an array of suppression words which I need to remove (the key/value pair) from the hash.

I tried [except and extract](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) and it seems nothing is being removed: *Was* is in the suppression list and in the result hash, even after I use except.

```
suppression_list.class    # => Array
suppression_list.first.class    # => String
result_hash.except(suppression_list)["was"]    # => 736.1234567901234
suppression_list.index("was")    # => 443
result_hash["was"]    # => 736.1234567901234
new = result_hash.except(suppression_list)
new["was"]    # => 736.1234567901234
new = result_hash.except!(suppression_list)
new["was"]    # => 736.1234567901234
result_hash["was"]    # => 736.1234567901234
```

Please help me remove the suppression list (keys and values) from `result_hash`.

Comment: It does not take an array. Please follow http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except and use the "splat operator".

Comment: You should add a Rails tag since you are open to using Rails methods.  A pure Ruby solution would be `result_hash.keep_if { |k,_| !suppression_list.include?(k) }`.

Comment: Cary, I only added active_support for this one thing, so I'm going to remove it and use your solution.  I'm glad to know about both now and to realize which is a rails and which is a pure ruby solution.  thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Hash#except`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except), [`Hash#except!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except-21) do not accepts an array of keys, but keys as arbitrary parameters. You need to use `*` operator to convert the array into method arguments:

```
result_hash.except(*suppression_list)
```

Comment: Huh.  I saw the * in the name of the method but I wonder why the examples in the guide that I linked to doesn't use the *.  They use an array of symbols in fact.  Anyway, thank you very much; this works for me!

Comment: @Darby, `*` in front of parameter name means it accepts arbitrary number of arguments. The arguments pass are collected into array and passed as a parameter.